# Assign RepeatedPtrField to repeated field in a protobuf message

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers, stdmove

I have a `RepeatedPtrField<M::Table>` and a protobuf message M as:

```
message M {
  message Table {
    optional string guid = 1;
    optional int64 schema_version = 2;
    optional int64 data_version = 3;
    repeated Column column = 4;
  }
  repeated Table table = 1;
}
```

How to I create a instance of M having the contents of RepeatedPtrField. I can write a for loop to copy data explicitly, but I am currently looking for something more concise, preferably using `std::move()` like optimization.

Comment: I did `state.mutable_table()->Swap(&table);`, where table was the RepeatedPtrField, and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a new version of Protobuf, like Protobuf 3.6.0, `RepeatedPtrField` defines move constructor, and you can call `std::move` to achieve your goal.

If you're using an old version, you have to call `Swap` to do the work, as you mentioned in the comment.